# Как правильно: ноль или нуль?

Tags: орфография

Ноль или нуль?
Как правильно писать это слово?

Answer (score 6):

> **Ноль** и **нуль** в свободном, не фразеологизированном, употреблении - равноправны. Но в некоторых устойчивых выражениях эти слова не взаимозаменяемы.
> Только **нуль** в выражениях: остричь под нуль; быть равным нулю; на улице на нуле; на нуле кто-что-нибудь, с нуля начинать (начать); сводить (сводиться); свести (свестись) к нулю; довести (доводить) до нуля; 
> Только **ноль** в выражениях: ноль-ноль, ноль внимания, ноль без палочки, 
> Нуль и ноль в выражениях: абсолютный нуль (чаще о человеке) и абсолютный ноль (термин).
> Прилагательные нолевой и нулевой закреплены в устойчивых выражениях: нулевое окончание, нулевая стрижка.
> **Правильно**
> в свободном употреблении ноль и нуль.

[Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_57). От себя добавлю, что "нуль" в качестве названия цифры, я почти никогда не слышал, почти всегда, *н**о**ль целых пять десятых*, но как синоним пустоты чаще слышал "нуль".

Answer (score 3):

Слова *нуль* и *ноль* заимствованы из немецкого языка, но восходят они к латинскому. Слово *ноль* соответствует краткому произношению латинской буквы u, а слово *нуль* – ее написанию.

Слова *ноль* и *нуль* употребляются одинаково часто, но не заменяют друг друга. Слово *ноль* является основной формой для ударной позиции основы слова, форма *нуль* в этом случае употребляется крайне редко. В безударной позиции корня употребляется только слово *нуль*, которое фактически является фонетической заменой для слова *ноль*. Это связано с тем, что для слова *ноль* обычная в этом случае редукция О/А нежелательна, например: *ноль целых пять десятых*, но: *равен нулю целых пяти десятым*.

Текстовые примеры: *Двенадцать ноль-ноль, дождь стучит за окном*. *Ноль – это Вселенная! Начало начал! Без свиты пиарщиков и журналистской обслуги – они ноль без палочки. На сцену – ноль внимания.*

*Температура – около нуля градусов.* Но: *сумма моментов сил равняется нулю. Без денег  бизнес с нуля может начать только Остап Бендер. Мы почитаем всех нулями, а единицами – себя. В военном искусстве он был нулём абсолютным.*

*За нулевой отсчет для географической долготы был принят гринвичский меридиан.* Но: *абсолютный нуль как физический термин, функция обращается в нуль как математическая формулировка*, где форма *нуль* в ударной позиции — исключение.